# Deploy\share a Delphi application

Tags: ms-access, delphi, rad

**Probably a noob question so bear with me...**

I need help to "release" my delphi application.
It's a fully written Delphi application that uses an Access Database. I just need a way to create an exe file or anything of that sort so that I can put it on a usb and run it on another PC *with* connected, working database tables.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. Are you looking for how to *use* your application *from* a USB drive? Or are you asking how to *deploy* your application *to* a USB drive?

Comment: You need to deploy and install Access on computers without Access. Search for "Access Redistributable" components.

Comment: FWIW, What you're trying to do is make a fully portable application / database combo. This is possible, but Access certainly isn't the best choice for portability. Each computer would require Access, as Victoria said. In fact, Microsoft themselves say for the Access Redistributable: "`This download will install a set of components that can be used to facilitate transfer of data between 2010 Microsoft Office System files and non-Microsoft Office applications.`" Having to install anything is not the right route for portability.

Comment: I dont think it is needed to install access itself, but only the drivers to connect with an access database.

Comment: As @Jerry Dodge pointed out relying on third-party components present on the machine your application is running on is not optimal for portable applications. For scenarios like this you are more likely to invest time on creating an installer or software package that will contain everything needed. The typical Setup.exe that contains third-party components, can verify if they are present, and will otherwise install them.

Comment: @GuidoG, yes, (most probably) ODBC driver. That's just included in that Access Redistributable package (which needs to be installed, probably because of registering that driver in the system). If you skipped the legal violation, you could just grab that driver (which will be one, or more libraries) and consume it without registering in the system (hence with no installation).

Comment: Do you not know how to copy a file to a USB drive?

Comment: @Lex, consider to use Firebird or SQLite as a database to get better results in terms of portability.

Comment: Which version and edition (professional/enterprise) are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking what you need to deploy, then you can get away with just copying the executable and the .mdb file into any folder or onto a USB drive.

It's been a while since I've deployed an application with an Access database, but I believe that the database engine is still installed by default along with Windows, so you don't need to worry about any other prerequisites.

Comment: Not a Microsoft Office product (Access), but the drivers (Jet4.0?) necessary to connect to different Microsoft products, including Access.

Comment: Jet4.0 It's been a part of every version of Windows since Windows 2000. I just checked Windows 7 and Windows 10 installations (and an old Server 2008) that didn't have Office installed. Of course, they're 32 bit, so you need to use the 32 bit ODBC Admin and look for MDB.

Comment: Indeed, I was blindly looking under the default 64bit ODBC setup. Completely forgot 32bit is separate.

Comment: @Jerry: Pretty much invalidates every comment you've posted, doesn't it? Maybe you should delete them before they influence voting.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the Application on USB and run it from anywhere without running some installer means *portable application*.

This accordingly means you should consider and assure "portable" feature when you develop and compile it.

Some things to take into consideration:

- Perform pre-requisites checks at the application start-up
- If not all pre-req are installed, like Access Runtime, treat it accordingly or install it silently
- Connect to the Access database after all checks in run-time
- Keep all configuration files on USB if you need persistent settings across devices
- Working with DBs on USB sticks, may affect performance due to its slowness

Beside portable, a regular application setup can be built using an installer like [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), with automatic installation of all dependencies. But this will *deploy* the application on running machine.